# Assignment error: "Cannot assign to array"

Tags: verilog, hdl, iverilog

I'm fairly new to Verilog and I'm trying to familiarize with it.
I'm building an ALU in Verilog, and when I try to assign the value from an operation to the `ALU_result` `reg`, I get the error listed above on the title.

```
parameter N = 8;
input  [N-1:0] inA, inB;
input    [3:0] op;

reg ALU_result[N-1:0] ;

always @(*)
    case(op)
      4'b0000:
        begin
          ALU_result = inA & inB ;
        end
      4'b0001:
        begin
          ALU_result = inA | inB ;
        end  
      4'b0010:
        begin
          ALU_result = inA + inB ;
        end
    endcase
```

The error I get more specifically.  I compiled the Verilog code with icarus verilog.

```
library.v:39: error: Cannot assign to array ALU_result. Did you forget a word index?
library.v:43: error: Cannot assign to array ALU_result. Did you forget a word index?
library.v:47: error: Cannot assign to array ALU_result. Did you forget a word index?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `ALU_result` as an unpacked array, but there is no need to do so.

Change:

```
reg ALU_result[N-1:0] ;
```

to:

```
reg [N-1:0] ALU_result;
```